# Alternative for DefaultTokenServices in spring security 6

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am doing migration of oauth2 from spring security 4.0.1 to 6.0.1 and found that  DefaultTokenServices has been removed in spring security 6
We were previously autowiring of  DefaultTokenServices as below:

```
private DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices;
```

I want to keep using my old authorization flow with the same behaviour as the DefaultTokenServices.

Is there any alternative to the same.

Comment: Is there any reason that you created a new account? What's wrong with your old account? https://stackoverflow.com/users/22805873/sejal-mirani